# 'obsoleting packages' in package manager output? [DNF]

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

I run Fedora on one of my PC's and for about  5 days my package manager, DNF, has had this persistent message:

dnf check-update

```
Obsoleting Packages
julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch                                           1:6.002-1.fc25                                       @updates
    julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch                                       1:6.002-1.fc25                                       @updates
julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch                                           1:6.002-1.fc25                                       updates 
    julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch                                       1:6.002-1.fc25                                       @updates
```

What is the correct way to deal with 'obsoleting packages' so that my package manager is clear of issues?

Comment: Not an issue. Asking for information `dnf check-update` and you get answers. The legit package `julietaula-montserrat-fonts` was updated to version `6.002-1.fc25` ten days ago.

Comment: I'm not following you. If it's not an issue then why has my package manager been displaying it for a few days. Do you expect it to go away?

Comment: What's wrong with running `dnf upgrade`?

Comment: `dnf upgrade` doesn't remove the message. That's what's wrong with `dnf upgrade` (in this instance).

Comment: `dnf check-upgrade` is telling you that there is a pending update which will cause that obsolete package to be removed. Are you saying that _after_ doing a `dnf upgrade` you still get that message? Did the upgrade give any errors?

Comment: This is the output from `dnf upgrade`:  Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:15 ago on Fri May 26 18:55:44 2017.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
The obsolete message is still there when I do dnf `check-update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So today I got this output from DNF when running `dnf check-update`:

> Fedora 25 - x86_64 - Updates
>   4.6 MB/s |  23 MB     00:05     Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:08 ago on Sat May 27 06:54:17 2017.
>
> dhcp-client.x86_64
>   12:4.3.5-2.fc25                                       updates 
>   dhcp-common.noarch
>   12:4.3.5-2.fc25                                       updates 
>   dhcp-libs.x86_64
>   12:4.3.5-2.fc25                                       updates 
>   gtk-update-icon-cache.x86_64
>   3.22.15-2.fc25                                        updates  gtk3.x86_64
>   3.22.15-2.fc25                                        updates  julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch         <-----Package is there
>
> 1:6.002-2.fc25                                        updates 
>   libinput.x86_64
>   1.6.3-5.fc25                                          updates  libsmbclient.x86_64
>   2:4.5.10-0.fc25                                       updates 
>   libwbclient.x86_64
>   2:4.5.10-0.fc25                                       updates 
>   oxygen-icon-theme.noarch
>   1:5.34.0-1.fc25                                       updates 
>   p11-kit.i686
>   0.23.2-4.fc25                                         updates  p11-kit.x86_64
>   0.23.2-4.fc25                                         updates  p11-kit-trust.x86_64
>   0.23.2-4.fc25                                         updates  samba-client.x86_64
>   2:4.5.10-0.fc25                                       updates 
>   samba-client-libs.x86_64
>   2:4.5.10-0.fc25                                       updates 
>   samba-common.noarch
>   2:4.5.10-0.fc25                                       updates 
>   samba-common-libs.x86_64
>   2:4.5.10-0.fc25                                       updates 
>   vte-profile.x86_64
>   0.46.2-1.fc25                                         updates  vte291.x86_64
>   0.46.2-1.fc25                                         updates  Obsoleting Packages julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch
>   1:6.002-1.fc25                                        @updates
>       julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch                                      1:6.002-1.fc25                                        @updates
>   julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch
>   1:6.002-2.fc25                                        updates 
>       julietaula-montserrat-fonts.noarch                                      1:6.002-1.fc25                @updates

This is after a week with the 'julietaula obsoleting package' message appearing. I then ran `dnf update` and the package was updated and I no longer receive the message about obsoleting.

It took a while but DNF sorted itself out automatically.